# Will ratio of two consistent estimator be consistent in general

Tags: self-study, consistency

If I have two statistic say $T_1$ and $T_2$ both of which are consistent for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, then will the ratio $\frac{T_1}{T_2}$ be also consistent for $\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}$ in general.

We have an invariance property for a continuous function of a consistent estimator. Can that property be extended for the function of two different estimator.

Comment: This looks like a one-step demonstration: provided $\theta_2\ne 0,$ isn't the function $(\theta_1,\theta_2)\to\theta_1/\theta_2$ continuous?

Comment: Yes, it is. I was just wondering if we can extend the invariance property for the two estimator case too.

Comment: Like if I have a normal distribution and I know $\bar{X}$ is consistent for $\mu$ and $S^2$ is consistent for $\sigma^2$, then can i say that $\frac{\bar{x}}{S^2}$ will be consistent for $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$

Comment: My point is that this is a *one* estimator case: the random variable $(T_1,T_2)$ estimates $(\theta_1,\theta_2).$

Comment: Ahh. I see what you are saying, we can look at this as a single estimator. I get it.